# Just moved my CakePHP. Autoload.php error. No such directory found

Tags: php, cakephp

Warning: require(/home5/golfbase/public_html/core/libs/current/Cake/Cache.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/web/web657276/golfbasen.dk/core/libs/current/AutoLoad.php on line 48

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home5/golfbase/public_html/core/libs/current/Cake/Cache.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/var/www/web/web657276/golfbasen.dk:/var/www/web/web657276/golfbasen.dk/app/') in /var/www/web/web657276/golfbasen.dk/core/libs/current/AutoLoad.php on line 48

That is the message that I'm receiving i just moved from another host... I think its the root dir. But i'm not really sure.... I hope you can help guys...

Comment: My guess is that the files don't exist there or you don't have proper permissions set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you copy the tmp files across from your old host?  Try deleting them.

If you're still having issues then try the accepted solution here:
[Odd issue with cakephp document root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029013/odd-issue-with-cakephp-document-root/21034807)

Answer (score 0):

in `php.ini` file, add the project folder path in `include_path` directive.

Comment: This won't help: the include path for the project is already there, based on the error message given.